# Failed to lookup view "error" after reinstalling windows?

Tags: node.js

Everything in my Node project worked perfectly, but then I decided to reinstall my Windows OS so I copyied all my project to Google drive. After i reinstalled, i went and downloaded my node project back to my desktop, installed node, and now i get this error:  Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Node\views".....Why is this happening?

I have already searched for multiple solutions, but all of them say that this part of the code is to blame:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'../public')));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. After reinstalling windows and sublime, when I inserted my project, the files got renamed from  index.ejs to index.ejs.html.... after getting rid of the ".html", everything worked perfectly.